# How to perform Polychoric Correlation with non-normal distributed variables

Tags: r, correlation, categorical-data, ordinal-data, likert

I want to perform a `polychoric correlation` on non-normal distributed underlying variables (which are in my case likert scaled). According to Joakim Ekström (["A Generalized Definition of the Polychoric Correlation Coeficient"](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj54LulvpDLAhXJwxQKHWT4CAAQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatistics.ucla.edu%2Fsystem%2Fresources%2FBAhbBlsHOgZmSSJiMjAxMi8wNS8xNi8xNV8xNF8yOV8yMF9BX0dlbmVyYWxpemVkX0RlZmluaXRpb25fb2ZfdGhlX1BvbHljaG9yaWNfQ29ycmVsYXRpb25fQ29lZmZpY2llbnQucGRmBjoGRVQ%2FA%2520Generalized%2520Definition%2520of%2520the%2520Polychoric%2520Correlation%2520Coefficient.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE4zf_x18xQNP7t-wsP869r9H4USQ&cad=rja)) you can perform the correlation with a large class of continuous bivariate distributions. I just do not know how to do the calculation. I checked all `R` packages with `Polychoric Correlation` I could find but non provides something like an argument for distribution moment parameters or something else. 
It would be nice, if anyone could tell me how I can calculate what I want and if the results are going to be robust.